# plink: unknown option "-q" error in Cruise Control

Tags: putty, cruisecontrol

I am getting the following error on configuring project on cruise control

Error Log

```
plink: unknown option "-q"
svn: E210002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://<uname>@<ip>/subversion/<folder1>/mconsole'
svn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly
<Update> failed.
```

I tried editing %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config  and removing "-q" option from ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh  but still its giving the same error.

My SVN Version  :

```
TortoiseSVN 1.7.10, Build 23359 - 64 Bit , 2012/10/08 11:46:26
Subversion 1.7.7
```

I have copied plink.exe from my putty folder to tortoise folded and renamed it to ssh.exe to solve ssh+svn issue

Can someone please help me to sort out the issue.